# LVM after drive order change

Tags: lvm

I've got an LV consisting of the two drives `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde`

I'm going to unplug the drives at `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`

So I'm guessing the drives that were `sdd` and `sde` will no longer be so

Will I be able to use the LVM after the drive change?

And is there any preparation I need to do before the unplug?

Answer (score 3):

LVM does not care about device names at all. It identifies the LVM physical volumes (PVs) by looking at all the disks and partitions the system can see and detecting valid LVM PVs and their LVM UUIDs. Then it sees if it can assemble complete volume groups (VGs) out of them, and activates any complete logical volumes (LVs) it can find automatically (unless auto-activation is disabled).

(If a LV is missing a part, you must activate it manually, using the `--partial` option of `lvchange`/`vgchange`.)

So, no, you don't have to do any special preparation and LVM should automatically detect your LV just as before.

Answer (score 2):

You are afraid that disks `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde` will be rename `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` ?

Yes they probably will.

Will this break LVM ?

No.

Disks were initialized using `pvcreate /dev/sdd /dev/sde` (or separatly, is doesn't matter).

The operation will write some meta information about volume group on disk, so your LVM structure will remain.

beware that if disk /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc are part of same volume group, you are likely to run into troubles.

use `pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdd` and `pvmove /dev/sdc /dev/sde` if need be.

use `vgreduce VG1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc` to remove disks from any VG (in that case VG1)

use `pvremove /dev/sdb /dev/sdc`

check with `pvlist` that those disk are no longer in a vg.

then disks can be unplug.

---

Edit after comment :

proceed as above if you want to disband data on removed disks.

If you want to keep data (move to anoter computer, replug after a while, etc), use

```
vgexport VGDATA
```

to write "LVM metadata" from VGDATA to disks, desactivate VGDATA (so disk can be removed)

use `vgimport /dev/sdX` or `vgscan` to recover data later on.

Comment: `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` are their own separate LVM, so are you saying that after removing the drives `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` I will still be able to access the LVM that was of `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde`? and do I need to "disband" the LVM of `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` prior to removal?

Answer (score 1):

> I've got an LV consisting of the two drives /dev/sdd and /dev/sde

LVs don't "consist" of two physical volumes. They might *reside* on two, but it's the volume group (VG) that consists of physical volumes.

> I'm going to unplug the drives at /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc

Do these belong to the same VG as your LV?

> And is there any preparation I need to do before the unplug?

Generally, before removing physical volumes (PVs) from a volume group, you want to use `vgreduce` to move all data on them to other PVs in the same VG, and then logically "disconnect" them from the volume group.

After you've **successfully** done that, removing them should not be a problem.

Comment: `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` are a separate LVM, will i need to do anything with this LVM prior to removal or can i just unmount it and remove the entry from `fstab`

Comment: there's no thing as a "separate LVM"; do you mean "separate VG"?

Comment: yes separate volume group, used in a different logical volume

Comment: so then there's nothing to worry about